# redux with angular2 does not return results

Tags: angular, redux, angular-http, azure-cognitive-search

I am using redux with angular2 and trying to call windows azure search. 
I wrote this code: 
types.ts

```
export interface IAppState {
  languageState?: LanguageState;
  searchState?: SearchState;
}
export type SearchState = si.Immutable<{
  searchResult: SearchResult;
  isLoading: boolean;
}>;
```

rootReducer:

```
export const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  searchState: searchReducer
});
```

search.reducer:

```
const INITIAL_SEARCH_STATE: SearchState = si.from({
  searchResult: new SearchResult(0, [], []),
  isLoading: false
});

export function searchReducer( state: SearchState = INITIAL_SEARCH_STATE, action: Action): SearchState {
  switch (action.type) {
    case SearchActions.SEARCH_RESULT_LOADING:  {
      return state.set('isLoading', true);
    };
    case SearchActions.SEARCH_RESULT_LOADED:  {
      return state.set('isLoading', false).set('searchResult', action['payload']);
    };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

search.actions:

```
@Injectable()
export class SearchActions {
  static SEARCH_RESULT_LOADING = 'SEARCH_RESULT_LOADING';
  static SEARCH_RESULT_LOADED = 'SEARCH_RESULT_LOADED';

  constructor(private ngRedux: NgRedux<IAppState>, private searchService: SearchService) { }

  search(searchItem: SearchItem) {
    const searchOptions = new SearchAzureOptions(searchItem);
    this.ngRedux.dispatch({
      type: SearchActions.SEARCH_RESULT_LOADING,
    });

    this.searchService.searchEntries(searchOptions.getSearchOptions()).subscribe(result => {
      this.ngRedux.dispatch({
        type: SearchActions.SEARCH_RESULT_LOADED,
        payload: result
      });
    });
  }
}
```

searchResult class:

```
export class SearchResult {
  count: number;
  products: Product[];
  Facets: Facet[];

  constructor(count: number, products: Product[], facets: Facet[]) {
    this.count = count;
    this.products = products;
    this.Facets = facets;
  }
}
```

search service:

```
searchEntries(searchOptions: any): Observable<SearchResult> {
    return this.http
      .post('link',
      searchOptions, new RequestOptions({ headers: this.headers }))
      .map(res => res.json())
      .map(row => new SearchResult(row['count'] as number, row['value'] as Product[], null))
      .retry(5)
      .catch((error: any) => this.searchHandleError(error));
  }
```

and the component:

```
@select()
  SearchState$: Observable<SearchState>;

  constructor(private actions: SearchActions) {
this.actions.search(searchItem);
}
```

html:

```
{{ (SearchState$ | async) == null }}
```

everything is to be okay and I can see the result in the Redux extension in the Chrome, which they are right. 
but I always get true as a result of my HTML. 
the redux is right. the service is right but I cannot find the problem.

any tip could be helpful. thank you
P.S. the JSON Object names are right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution after 4 hours struggling: 
the problem was with small letter, capital letter thing.

in component:

```
@select()
  searchState$: Observable<SearchState>;
```

's'earchState$ instead of 'S'earchState$

Answer (score 2):

Azure Search is working on a redux library to query and build UI against the service. Have you tried using it? It is well tested and avoids common pitfalls: https://github.com/EvanBoyle/AzSearchStore